# Resize bitmap inside a drawable layer-list

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, styles

Currently I'm developing a Android application. I want to make a text (a header) with a background that looks like this:

```
 _______
/______/
```

I have the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>    
            <gradient
              android:startColor="@color/jaarkleur"
              android:centerColor="@color/jaarkleur"
              android:endColor="#E66C2C00"
              android:angle="0" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"
            />       
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/overlay_left" android:gravity="left"  />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/overlay_right" android:gravity="right"  />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

So I made to images so with a transparant triangle which are placed at both ends.

This works fine for headers with only one line, but when a header takes up two lines it looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/lDQGo.png]

So my question is: Is it possible to resize both images so looks correctly?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked into using a 9-patch?

Comment: Yes, but i don't want to use a 9-patch, i want to keep the 'inner' color variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved it using two (half-transparant) images which represent the corners.

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
                <shape>    
                    <gradient
                      android:startColor="@color/jaarkleur"
                      android:centerColor="@color/jaarkleur"
                      android:endColor="#E66C2C00"
                      android:angle="0" />
                    <stroke android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"
            />       
                </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/overlay_left" android:gravity="left|top"  />
        </item>
        <item>
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/overlay_right" android:gravity="right|bottom" />
        </item>        
</layer-list>
```

Comment: you can also use `android:gravity="right|fill_vertical"` and `android:gravity="left|fill_vertical"` to scale your right and left bitmaps vertically

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a layer-list with gradient / border stroke and a custom image, consider using a [NinePatchDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch).

There is also a handy 9-patch [creater](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) that comes with the android SDK.

Comment: The reason I want to use gradient color is because the variable "jaarkleur" can change. It is easier to just modify this variable then to make a whole new background-image.