# How can I add an Image in my custom shape xml

Tags: xml, android-layout, android

I'm writing an XML selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_state2" android:state_pressed="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_state1"/>
</selector>
```

I just want state1 to be transparent.So that the image to be seen as - is

**state1**

```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:startColor="#00000000" />
```

Now I want state2 to shade the pic a bit which I have accomplished already. My problem is that other than the shading gradient I want an icon to appear on the center. I don't know how to add this through xml

**state2**

```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="#80000000"
    android:startColor="#80000000" />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by using layer-list for ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item>
  <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
      <gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="#80000000"
    android:startColor="#80000000" />
  </shape>
 </item>
 <item>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/background"
android:tileMode="repeat" android:gravity="center" />
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

Save the above as @drawable/image_state2.

For more info:
[Resize bitmap inside a drawable layer-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608019/resize-bitmap-inside-a-drawable-layer-list)

Comment: that's  perfect!! you are saving me today, thank you very much :) do you know how I can have it centered? and if possible set it's dimensions?

Comment: try setting gravity to center  android:gravity="center" for bitmap

Comment: yeah I found on my own that last one thank you very much