# Bitmap in shape drawable

Tags: android, android-layout

I create the following drawable but the bitmap object does not showing! any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/some_drawable"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />

    <stroke
        android:width="8dp"
        android:color="#ffffff" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="6dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="6dp"
        android:topRightRadius="6dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: I think you need to create a layer list, [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9700235/2823516)

Comment: sorry to catch you here, i found from google that you had same problem as mine with proguard and parse, have you managed to solve it?
could you tell me how?
[link])http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230719/parse-com-not-working-after-proguard/31230788)

Comment: @MuhammadNaderi Check your OP bro.